# DropDownList selected value not getting set

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using two dropdowns for Month and Year selection, I have made a user control and I am having this control inside a repeater control.
I have to show the selected values from database in them. for eg if in database it is 5/2014 then it should show May in Month drop down and 2014 in year drop down.
I am doing this in RowDatabound event, but its not getting selected.
This is how I am doing

```
var txtFrom = e.Item.FindControl("txfrom") as TextBox;//I will have values in mm/yyy
var datefrom = e.Item.FindControl("ddempfrom") as CutomControls.MonthYearPicker;
var monthfrom = datefrom1.FindControl("ddmonth") as DropDownList;
var yearfrom = datefrom1.FindControl("ddyear") as DropDownList;

monthfrom.SelectedValue=txtFrom.Text.Split('/')[0];
yearfrom .SelectedValue=txtFrom.Text.Split('/')[1];
```

and this is how I am making dropdownlists in UserControl

```
private void LoadMonthYear()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        DateTime date = new DateTime(1900, i, 1);
        ddmonth.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(date.ToString("MMMM"), i.ToString()));
    }

    var currentYear = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 1900; i <= Convert.ToInt32(currentYear.ToString("yyyy")); i++)
    {
        ddyear.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
    }   
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    LoadMonthYear();
}
```

I tried debugging and when break point comes to the line where I am setting selected value, after going to next line,the selectedvalue appears to be blank

My DropDown Lists

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddmonth" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
-
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddyear" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Update: I noticed that `RowDataBound` is hitting first then `Page_Load` of Usercontrol is hiting

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to select the value in the dropdowns BEFORE the `Page_Load` in the usercontrol has been fired, so there are no items to select at that point.  Try moving the call to `LoadMonthYear()` into your `Page_Init` instead

Comment: Could it be the typo here: `var txtFrom = e.Item.FindControl("txfrom") as TextBox;`. You used **txfrom** instead of **txtfrom**.

Comment: I would try to trigger the LoadMonthYear(); from within your ItemDataBound handler of your repeater.  e.g. var monthfrom = datefrom1.FindControl("ddmonth") as DropDownList; monthfrom.LoadMonths()

Comment: @Matthijs its txfrom on repeater

Comment: @freefaller let me try

Comment: Do  your dropdownlists contain all values?

Comment: @Steven You mean I should set values of drop down in DataBound?

Comment: @lnanikian Yes they have all values

Comment: @Syed, Actually, OnDataBinding handler of the dropdown might give a better result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put for example on your dropdowns in your user control, an OnDataBinding event handler

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server" OnDataBinding="ddlMonth_DataBinding">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddyear" runat="server" OnDataBinding="ddlYear_DataBinding">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And then make event handlers in the code behind of the user control

```
protected void ddlMonth_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(sender);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            DateTime date = new DateTime(1900, i, 1);
            ddl.Items.Add(newSystem.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(date.ToString("MMMM"), i.ToString()));
        }
}

protected void ddlYear_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(sender);
    var currentYear = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 1900; i <= Convert.ToInt32(currentYear.ToString("yyyy")); i++)
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
    }   
}
```

}

After that you set your dropdown value from within the repeater OnItemDataBound event

Comment: This will be in my Usercontrol?